# AJAX - posting JSON to controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to make a call to the deprecated Google Finance API (just to learn) parsing the response and post it to my controller. I show the user a view with 0 values but once the response returns, I will display the parsed results.

The results look perfect except that the view is printed to the console instead of being displayed. What am I overlooking here? Any other feedback is also welcome as I'm just trying to learn ASP.NET MVC.

Here is my code:

HomeController:

```
    public ActionResult Index3()
    {
        var model = from a in realList orderby a.Symbol select a;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index3(string JSON)
    {
        // parse response...
        // listOfStocks.Add(...);

        var model = from a in listOfStocks orderby a.Symbol select a;

        return View(model);
    }

    static List<Stocks> listOfStocks = new List<Stocks>();
```

Index3:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Stocks>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stock Texter";
}
<h2>Stock List</h2>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Symbol)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Change)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ChangePercent)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PreviousClose)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Symbol)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Change)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChangePercent)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PreviousClose)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


@section JavaScript
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/test.js")"></script>
}
```

test.js:

```
(function ($, window, document) {
    var data = "";
    $.when(
        $.getJSON("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL,JPM,CAT,MSFT&callback=?", function (response) {
            data = response;
            console.log("call succcessful");
        })
    ).then(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/index3",
            data: { 'JSON': JSON.stringify(data) },
            success: function (response2) {
                console.log(response2);
            }
        });
    });
}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Posting-JSON-Data-to-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your current code is logging the response from ajax call to the console in the `success` event.

Ideally you should return the markup needed to display the table from your ajax call. So it is better to move that to a partial view which we can re use. Create a partial view called "Results.cshtml" and move the code to render the table there.

*Here i am simply using the p tag instead of writing all the code to render the table. You may replace with your original code (needed to render the table) from the question here*

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Stocks>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.Symbol</p>
  <!-- You can change this table rendering code as you have in the question. -->
}
```

Now call this partial view in your main view(`Index3.cshtml`) for the initial page load. Wrap the call to the partial view in a container div

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Stocks>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stock Texter";
}
<h2>Stock List</h2>
<div id="resultContainer">
  @Html.Partial("Results",Model)
</div>
```

Now for your ajax call, return this partial view only

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index3(string JSON)
{
    //  to do : Your code
    var model = from a in listOfStocks orderby a.Symbol select a;

    return PartialView("Results",model);
}
```

Now in the ajax call's success event, instead of writing to the console, update the container div.

```
success: function (response2) {
            $("#resultContainer").html(response2);
        }
```

Comment: This did it, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please review my answer to help with your question.  If you want me to look into more answers, please let me know.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index59</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function (ev) {
                (function ($, window, document) {
                    var data = "";
                    $.when(
                        $.getJSON("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL,JPM,CAT,MSFT&callback=?", function (response) {
                            data = response;
                            console.log("call succcessful");
                        })
                    ).then(function () {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Home/GetData",
                            data: { 'JSON': JSON.stringify(data) },
                            success: function (response2) {
                                var ap = "dh";
                                //You have to manually assign each value or use a partial view
                                var theArr = JSON.parse(response2);
                                var apdg = "dh";
                                jQuery.each(theArr, function (index, value) {
                                    //selecting all rows, just selecting two fields
                                    $("#theData").append(" e=" + value.e + " ltt=" + value.ltt)
                                    //you would set the field based on id
                                    //$("#MyField").val(value.ltt)
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }(window.jQuery, window, document));
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="theData"></div>
    <input type="button" value="GetData" id="btn" />
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
   public string GetData(string JSON)
    {
        return JSON;
    }
```